# how to save array of elements into the csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I am having array of elements like this:

```
['1X2', 'Double Chance', 'O/U 2.5']

[1-1.95,X-3.30,2-4.05,1X-1.17,12-1.25,X2-1.70,Over-2.40,under-1.53]
```

from these arrays I want the csv file like this:

```
1x2 -1-1,95,X-3.30,2-4.05
Double Chance - 1X-1.17,12-1.25,X2-1.70
O/U 2.5 - Over-2.40,Under-1.53
```

row-wise the elements should be inserted in csv file.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of you want to merge the 2 arrays?

Comment: @Chelmy88 I didnt get you

Comment: I look like you have two arrays: `['1X2', 'Double Chance', 'O/U 2.5']` and `[1-1.95,X-3.30,2-4.05,1X-1.17,12-1.25,X2-1.70,Over-2.40,under-1.53]`, and that you want to insert some element in the first array into the second and output to csv, but I don't understand exactly how. E.g. why will you take `Double Chance`, concatenate it with `- 1X-1.17`, and add in the same line the elements `12-1.25, X2-1.70`?

Comment: Actually I had scrapped them from a website so I want to represent them in the table format@ Chelmy88